# Magento 2 - How get extension attributes from product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection, extension-attributes

I need to get the product collection with all extension attributes, specifically I need then to get the stockItem object with `$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()`. So I have created a function like this:

```
protected function getCollection(ProductInterface $product): Collection
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['eq' => Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq' => Status::STATUS_ENABLED])
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $product->getId()])
        ->setPageSize(5);

    return $collection;
}
```

then I get all items from collection with `$collection->getItems()`, but in the loop of `getItems()` the extension attributes are `null`, why and how can I get them?

```
protected function populateProductList(Collection $collection)
{
    $items = $collection->getItems();

    $products = array_map(function ($product): ProductInterface {
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        var_dump($stockItem);die; // IS NULL

        return $product;
    }, $items);

    return $products;
}
```

If I get a Product from the get method of productRepository, that product has all extension attributes compiled, I don't want to use productRepository to get another time the products for "only" the extension attributes, I want to avoid another call for performance reasons.

Comment: Did you manage to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getData` to get complete object Data

```
protected function populateProductList(Collection $collection)
{
    $items = $collection->getItems();

    $products = array_map(function ($product): ProductInterface {
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData();
        var_dump($stockItem);die; // IS NULL

        return $product;
    }, $items);

    return $products;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `getStockItem()` is null

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the stock Item in the product repository load is because we have a plugin to set it

\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\AfterProductLoad

```
public function afterLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $productExtension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $productExtension->setStockItem($this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId()));
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension);
        return $product;
    }
```

In you case if you are just interested only in the $stockItem you can just try the following this way you can avoid loading the product again.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    /** \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry */
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
}
```

Hope this helps